# Impala: ERROR: AnalysisException: Partition spec does not exist:

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, impala

I am trying to query for:

`show files in tableA partition (column_key1=value1, column_key2=value2)`

However, that throws off an error: 

`ERROR: AnalysisException: Partition spec does not exist: (column_key1=value1, column_key2=value2)`

whereas this partition does exist, and also has the necessary files I'm looking in the table.

The objective is to first check if the partition exists, if so, show the files in that partition.

Related: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Partition-Spec-Does-Not-Exist-error/td-p/33460