# Impala not showing correct list of partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, impala

An external table had one of its partitions dropped on Hive. When

```
SHOW PARTITIONS elevationP;
```

is run on Hive, the updated list of partitions is displayed. However on Impala, even after :

```
REFRESH elevationP;
```

and

```
INVALIDATE METADATA elevationP;
```

when

```
SHOW PARTITIONS elevationP;
```

is run, the dropped partition is still being displayed.
Dropping it the same way on Impala using:

```
ALTER TABLE elevationP DROP PARTITION(degrees='60');
```

didn't work either and showed:

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Partition spec does not exist: (degrees='60').

I saw rather similar unresolved issues that went unanswered (see bellow), does anybody know how to get Impala to correctly update the metadata and refresh the partition list?

---

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Partition-Spec-Does-Not-Exist-error/td-p/33460

[Impala: ERROR: AnalysisException: Partition spec does not exist:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739022/impala-error-analysisexception-partition-spec-does-not-exist)

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-2423

Comment: try msck repair in hive first and then do the invalidate/refresh in impala. Its a workaround though

Comment: Just out of curiosity: did you try syntax variants such as `INVALIDATE METADATA default.elevationP` and `INVALIDATE METADATA` (the latter may require a priviledged account)? Also, since _"INVALIDATE METADATA waits to reload the metadata when needed for a subsequent query"_ (quoting the Cloudera documentation), did you try to run a dummy SELECT query to see if it actually did trigger the metadata reload?

Comment: And finally, did you check whether the `INVALIDATE` and `SHOW` were running on the same node, or different nodes? Maybe the issue is in the _catalogd_ daemon that is supposed to keep all nodes in sync -- but it is not extremey stable, and has no HA.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys
@KSNidhin msck repair and a invalidate/refresh didn't help either

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Could you tell me where I can see which nodes are executing the commands?

Comment: Check the logs for Impala Daemons in Cloudera Manager. Each query has a "coordinator" node that prepares the execution plan based on its cached metadata.